# Save images from URL

Tags: php

I have a URL that's in this format

```
http://site.com/image.php?id=1
```

Each ID is a different photo, how can I save each image for 1000 ids?

Comment: you can explain more what is for 1000 ids ?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Are you sure there are 1000 ids? Have you tried file_get_contents?

Comment: You are looking for file functions? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: I'm saying each ID has a different image, so.. http://site.com/image.php?id=1, http://site.com/image.php?id=2, etc I want to save the image for each one in a folder.

Comment: loop{ file_get_contents("http://site.com/image.php?id=".$i++); } #psuedo

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like (assuming they are jpg imags and your id's are all consecutive):

```
for($i=0;$i<=1000;$i++) {
    $url = 'http://site.com/image.php?id='.$i;
    file_put_contents('image'.$i.'.jpg', file_get_contents($url));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an inbuilt function for this, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php